# Is it okay to send a gentle reminder to professor

Tags: etiquette, email

I sent an email to some professor about a month back for some research paper. He reply to me that he will scan the research paper and send me in few weeks. I think he has forget to send the scanned document. Should I send him a gentle reminder?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's OK to send a reminder. Generally, if it's been a week since you expected an answer, it's probably fine to ask.